# Navigation bar and Page Buttons missing in Master Details Page

Tags: xamarin

Could someone help me with a bit of Xamarin.
How do we add Navigation Bar and Page Buttons in a Master Detail Page in Xamarin ?
I added a MasterDetail page, and defined the xaml as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.Views;assembly=MyNameSpace"
                  prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
                  x:Class="MyNameSpace.Views.MainMenu">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master BackgroundColor ="White">
    <ContentPage Title="Master Page"  BackgroundColor = "#2c3e50" >
<Grid BackgroundColor ="#354b60">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"  />
      <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
          <Button BackgroundColor="#2c3e50" TextColor="White" Text="Menu 1"  ></Button>
          <Button BackgroundColor="#2c3e50" TextColor="White" Text="Menu 2"  ></Button>
        </StackLayout>
</Grid>



    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <local:MainPage/>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Am I missing out something ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I am not able to add a Icon Next to title of Details page.

Comment: The question doesn't reflect that at all. Pleas update your question so it's clear what the problem is and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your Detail page in a NavigationPage:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:MainPage/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

That should give you a navigation bar at the top.

Comment: Thanks, that did help. One quick question though. Currently am using a NavigateCommand to load other menu pages when the buttons are clicked. " _NavigationService.NavigateAsync(name);". So with your approach, how should I change it to so that the navigation bar is seen in pages that are loaded too ?

Comment: I am not familiar with MVVMLight (I assume that is what you are using) so I do not know. If you were to load new pages with the Xamarin.Forms PushAsync() method then the Navigation bar will remain. There are some discussions on this on our forums. Here is one that may be of interest: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37775/using-inavigationservice-mvvm-light-vs-forms-navigation